# How to show only few with toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this working jsfiddle with markup and some jquery.

This works fine. But I want to do the exact same thing (toggle) with a table. As you can see in this working fiddle, it shows only a few of the information at first, but when you click the button it appears more info. How can I do the same thing with a table?

```
<section class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Price example section start -->
    <div class="innerAreaWithHeading innerAreaBottom padding span8 offset2 toggleContent">

        <h2 class="text-center h1">Header</h2>
        <p class="big">
            Text
        </p>

        <div class="nsRow innerAreaTop innerAreaBottom border-gray">
            <div class="nsSpan6">
                <div class="padding">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Header</h3>
                    <p class="price text-center text-pink xl">
                        Text
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="nsSpan6">
                <div class="bg-gray padding priceBox">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Header</h3>
                    <p class="price text-center text-turquoise xl">
                        Text
                    </p>
                    <div class="priceTriangleDown"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Toggle hide/show content -->
        <div class="nsRow innerAreaTop innerAreaBottom border-gray priceExaples" style="display: none;">
            <div class="nsSpan6">
                <div class="padding">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Header</h3>
                    <p class="price text-center text-pink xl">
                         Text
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="nsSpan6">
                <div class="bg-gray padding priceBox">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Header</h3>
                    <p class="price text-center text-turquoise xl">
                        Text
                    </p>
                    <div class="priceTriangleDown"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nsRow innerAreaTop innerAreaBottom border-gray priceExaples" style="display: none;">
            <div class="nsSpan6">
                <div class="padding">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Header</h3>
                    <p class="price text-center text-pink xl">
                        Text
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="nsSpan6">
                <div class="bg-gray padding priceBox">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Header</h3>
                    <p class="price text-center text-turquoise xl">
                        Text
                    </p>
                    <div class="priceTriangleDown"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End toggle hide/show content -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <button data-toggle=".priceExaples"
                data-togglevisibletext="See more examples"
                data-togglehiddentext="See less examples"
                class="btnRounded btnRounded-inverted">
                See less examples</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

$('[data-toggle]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var toggle = $this.attr("data-toggle");
    // Scope triggered area
    var $context = $(toggle);

    var attr1 = $(this).attr('data-toggleHiddenText');
    var attr2 = $(this).attr('data-toggleVisibleText');
    if (typeof attr1 !== typeof undefined && attr1 !== false &&
        typeof attr2 !== typeof undefined && attr2 !== false) {
        // Toggle text on buttons
        var txt = $context.is(':visible') ? attr1 : attr2;
        $this.text(txt);
    }

    // Show/hide more content
    $context.slideToggle('fast');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbtxs5rt/1/

Comment: First create a table and post it here..

Comment: @AnoopJoshi All right

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I made "an ugly" fix but it didn't really solve all the problems, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/4bnw28tv/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi As you can see, I've made two tables. The first shows only a few information and when I hit the button, it replaces the first table with the second. But the button-text doesn't change... I hope you get the idea even if the content is in swedish...

Comment: you want to toggle the elements with data attribute?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi not sure what you mean. Basically I want the two first rows in the table to be visible at all time, like a "teaser". But when I press the button, the rest of the table to be visible. Do you get what I'm trying to say?

Comment: [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/4bnw28tv/12/)

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4bnw28tv/18/

Comment: @Pete exactly! Thank you :D That's how I want it :) But I also want the button you click to change content from "Show" to "Hide" depending if you only see two rows or all rows.

Comment: have updated fiddle in answer below - just change the text for the button to be whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table and comments you can achieve what you want using the following jQuery:

```
var tbody = $('tbody'),
    rows = tbody.children('tr:gt(1)'),
    button = $('<button>Visa tabell</button>');

rows.hide().closest('table').after(button);

button.click(function () {    
    if (tbody.hasClass('shown')) {
        rows.fadeOut(function () {
            tbody.removeClass('shown');
            button.text('Visa tabell');
        });
    } else {
        rows.fadeIn(function () {
            tbody.addClass('shown');
            button.text('Dölj tabellen');
        });
    }          
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4bnw28tv/26/)

Comment: Yes, that's more like it! Thank you! :D

Comment: there's one problem though. If you check my first post with the code. That jQuery and this jQuery you wrote doesn't work together because they use the same function. How can I separate these two? Is it because they use [data-toggle]? Can I use a class-name inside data-toggle?

Comment: Just realised you don't need the each loop and [this should fix your other problem](http://jsfiddle.net/4bnw28tv/26/).  It creates the button dynamically and appends it after the table - you shouldn't need it if js is disabled.  Also not sure if I have the button text the right way round

Comment: no worries, I figured it out myself! Thank you for the help anyways :)